# could you explain the meaning of sentence given below

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am unable to understand the meaning of the sentence, please explain meaning of sentence

> I accepted another one-year appointment at Berkeley **in an attempt to postpone the good fortune awaiting me** and the consequent issue it would finally force.

In above sentence till the Highlighted line i understood like: *He accepted 1 year appointment to postpone the good fortune that is awaiting for him.*

Comment: What part of it is causing you trouble?  What do you think it means?  Without more details, we don't know what it is you don't understand.

Comment: Do you have a source for it? In all honesty, I'm a native speaker and I'm struggling to figure out what it means too (at best there's context missing, at worst it's ambiguously written).

Comment: @Jez: Looks pretty straightforward to me. The writer is wryly acknowledging that there's something due to happen to him which *he* isn't exactly looking forward to (but which others would describe as a "good" thing), because when it does there will be an awkward issue to be dealt with. And by implication, going to Berkeley will put the matter off (for some reason which is presumably obvious if you know the full context).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sentence is a little confusing because it is communicating several different ideas.  We can make it more clear by breaking it up into simpler sentences.

> I accepted another one-year appointment at Berkeley in an attempt to postpone the good fortune awaiting me and the consequent issue it would finally force.

Could also be said as follows:

> 1) I accepted a one-year appointment at [The University of California] Berkeley.
>
> 2) This was not my first appointment.
>
> 3) This was an attempt to postpone two things.
>
> 4) Good fortune was awaiting me [and postponed by my appointment].
>
> 5) The good fortune would force another issue [to be resolved.]

However, even split up in this way it is difficult to understand, because the author is using irony or sarcasm to communicate a meaning that is the opposite of what is being said.  The reader is expected to understand the meaning through context.

Here is an example of verbal irony or sarcasm:

> A) "Hey, is that your car?  It's on fire."
>
> B) "Oh, that's *just great*."

We understand that in "B" above, the speaker does not sincerely believe it is great that their car is on fire.  Instead, they have used sarcasm to communicate the exact opposite in a humorous or unexpected way. Sarcasm is often indicated with a particular tone or expression, but it's difficult to present that in text.

In the sentence about the appointment at Berkeley, we know that the author took the appointment willingly because of "3" - this was an attempt to postpone the things that followed.

If "4" was genuinely good fortune, it would be strange for the author to attempt to postpone it.  However, if the author does not agree that it is genuinely good fortune, the sentence makes more sense.  For instance, they may be committed to an arranged marriage after graduation, and disagree that it will be "good fortune".  The author is calling it good fortune but we are expected to understand it will be something entirely undesirable.

Reading "4" as sarcasm makes "5" more clear.  When the "good fortune" the author is talking about comes to pass, another issue will be forced.  This means that the author will have to resolve an issue they have been avoiding.  For example, they may have to admit that they no longer want the arranged marriage.

Answer (score 0):

One year appointments are given to junior faculty or post-doctorate students so they can finish some of their research.

It sounds like this person, who is obviously intelligent (Berkley), is postponing the inevitability of **life** and may be falling into the trap of becoming a [career student](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=career+student).

A possible storyline might be he has a significant other who is waiting for him to leave school and get a job in the **real world** which would then force the consequent issue (marriage).
But maybe that's just me reading into it...